# Str_replace issue when using html

Tags: php

I am trying to build a system where users can edit news stories. When they add images to the stories they will type #IMG1# if it is the image with id 1 they want in there.

When they upload the news, the #IMG1# code is `str_replace()` with something like this: `<div id="image"><img src="images/image1.jpg"></div>`

The issue for me is when they want to edit the news again, I want to replace all the image codes back, so the user sees the #IMG1# again, but it seems I cannot `str_replace()` back because of the html codes and the quotation marks? Is this true?

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Store your data with `#iMG#` but replace this `#IMG#` when you __output__ news item, not on save.

Comment: @u_mulder I am not following you here. I have no issue showing the stuff I want, that works perfectly. The issue is when editing the news again, then I want to show the #IMG1# instead of the entire html code because it is not showed properly in the editor.

Comment: Do not replace `#IMG1#` with `<img>` when you save data.

Comment: Seems like a better solution now yes, I'll try that!

Comment: Thank you @u_mulder that was way easier!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise to leave news' text as is, with `#IMG1#` placeholders.

Only when you output this text for viewing - replace `#IMG1#` with `<img>` tag, but when user edits text - he still sees `#IMG1#` and can edit it.

Of course, as you will replace `#IMG1#` placeholders on **each** output, this can slower your system. As a solution - you can add additional field like `renderedContent` and on saving data render news text to this field and when output for viewing - take content from this field.